# VS Code plugin to notify me when external github issues are fixed

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I depend on multiple open source projects, and every so often I have to write workarounds until an external issue is fixed, for example:

```dart
# TODO: Remove workaround once the http library supports canceling requests.
# https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/424
... the workaround ...
```

It would be useful to somehow track when those external issues get fixed. I couldn't find a plugin or other method to do this when the projects are external.

Any suggestions on how to track this?